# How to fix setup.py file at py2app

Tags: python, py2app

I have spent weeks creating a stand-alone application using py2app for my project but nothing works. Actually, I have created a setup.py file and add all packages I am using but the application from dist do not work but using terminal works. For example, I created an app with PyQt5 add all packages and it was working. But in my project, there are a lot of libs and another problem is that I need to add backend and some other modules to stand alone version.

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['__main__.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'site_packages': True, 'includes':['Brotli', 'certifi', 'chardet', 'click', 'dash', 'dash-core-components', 'dash-html-components', 'dash-renderer', 'dash-table', 'Flask', 'Flask-Compress', 'future', 'idna', 'itsdangerous', 'Jinja2', 'joblib', 'MarkupSafe', 'numpy', 'ordered-set', 'pandas', 'plotly', 'PyLaTeX', 'PyQt5', 'PyQt5-sip', 'python-dateutil', 'pytz', 'requests', 'retrying', 'scikit-learn', 'scipy', 'six', 'sklearn', 'threadpoolctl', 'urllib3', 'Werkzeug', 'xlrd', 'pandas._libs.tslibs.base', ]}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

the full project includes: main.py, dist backend, GUI, logs

what do I need to add to setup.py?

Comment: My advise would be to simplify your question so you ask one thing.  "Nothing works" is not helpful debug information.  So you have your setup.py file, what do you do, what happens, do you get errors etc?

Comment: Your opening paragraph is very stream-of-consciousness. Please simplify and structure it to state the specific thing that you cannot get to work and what problem you see. Be precise. "It doesn't work" isn't useful. "I get the following error: [error pasted from terminal]" will give us information to work with.